# qTip not working when hovering over image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, qtip

I'm creating a Type 101 page and I'm trying to create an interactive section for the anatomy of letterforms. Here's a link so you can get an idea of what I'm talking about: http://willryan.us/test/#anatomyBox

I plan on having it where you hover over different parts of the image and a qTip pops up with a definition of the part you're looking at. For some reason, I can't even get the qTip to show. I've tried everything I could think of but it's still not working.

Here's what I have:

**HTML**

```
    <div id="anatomyBox">
            <div id="anatomy">
                <h1>ANATOMY</h1>
                <h2>You're saying a letter has different parts?!</h2>
                <p>Type Fun01 was created to Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum luctus ante vitae orci dapibus sollicitudin. Nam pretium volutpat blandit. Sed tristique nunc ut justo gravida sollicitudin.</p>

                <p>Nulla facilisi. Duis sit amet libero a massa aliquet auctor vitae eget quam. Donec est magna, porttitor id porta eget, porttitor a ante. Nam felis dolor, aliquet vel vulputate vitae, lacinia sed leo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In at diam in nisi varius tincidunt.</p>

                <p>What is typography? We've known each other for so long Your heart's been aching but you're too shy to say it Inside we both know what's been going on We know the game and we're gonna play it And if you ask me how I'm feeling Don't tell me you're too blind to see</p>
            </div>

            <div id="anatomyMap1">
                <img src="assets/images/anatomy_1.png" width="804" height="114" alt="Clarendon">
            </div>
```

**JS** (in head tag)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

 <!-- add q-tip-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
           $('#anatomy img').qtip({
           content: 'This is an image',
           show: 'mouseover',
           hide: 'mouseout'
        });
    });
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?! It seems like super simple javascript but it's not working. And I'm obviously not quite there yet, but what's the best way to hover over different sections of one image and see different tooltips? I was looking into image maps and it seems like that could work... One step at a time I guess.

Comment: [Your demo site is using version 1 of qTip from 2009](http://willryan.us/test/js/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.js).  Please upgrade to [qTip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/) to avoid any bugs or conflicts with the latest version of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in the plugin...

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined"
```

This line of code is causing the error...

```
if($.browser.msie) self.elements.tooltip.get(0).style.removeAttribute('filter');
```

It's meant to be for IE7, so wouldnt be a big deal if you removed it.

Also the image is not within `#anatomy`

Should be `#anatomyMap1 img`

I've commented out the old IE stuff and it works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/9PEVn/

You might want to look at Qtip2 at a later stage

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/

Comment: What? Where?! This is my first time using qTip so I figured I messed up something basic...

Comment: Ahh damn it! Thanks for spotting that. I fixed it and updated the live version, still doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: Got rid of that line, still no luck. And it looks like my FancyBox images on the page are broken too. This is so frustrating! Thanks for your help though.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! Weird that some default code would be causing the problem... Glad it's fixed though. Thanks again!

Comment: It's no wonder you found a bug in the plugin, he's using version 1 of qTip from 2009.

Comment: No worries, glad to help. Looks like the developer of the plugin lost the plot a bit.

Comment: It's really not the developer's fault the user installed a 4-year old version of the plugin along with the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: Just tried using qTip2 and it doesn't seem to work, even after commenting out the same line of code Alex talked about...

Comment: Yes indeed, he is allowed to use whatever he wants.  And when the out-of-date plugin fails, it's still not the developer's fault.

Comment: The plugin is a bit dodgey in general, maybe have a look for something different.

Comment: @WillRyan, qTip2 is not a direct "drop-in" replacement for version 1.  Your code needs to be changed to work with it.  http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/converter/

Comment: I like the look of that.  Is there a browser compatibility matrix listed?

Comment: Hover over the browser icons.

Comment: Oh yeah... right there in front of my nose while blending into the background.  lol... so far, looks good.

Comment: lol yeah, not sure thats a good or bad thing that it wasnt that obvious. Think the developer just wanted to show off their plugin ;-)

Comment: ToolTipster looks pretty usable, definitely going to check it out. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: The comments are not a good place for long discussions, please move to the chat if you want to continue!